# How to give permission for a role for editing help text for fields of custom types?

Tags: 7, users

I want role "RoleFoo" to have only the permission to edit the Help Text of all fields of  specific content types (contentypefoo1 and contentypefoo2).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Field help helper](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_help_helper) module seems to be a good fit for this. some more details about it (from its project page, which is also here the image originates from):

> The Field help helper module adds a link to entity configurable fields so that users with the appropriate permissions may easily edit the help text and label for a field in context of where the field displays.
>
> Once a user's role is given the Edit field help text permission any user with that permission will be able to edit the help text or label of a configurable field without having access to administer fields.

[image]

**Extra bonus**: comes wth an official release for both D7 and D8 ...

Comment: Please verify the edited version of your answer. Feel free to rollback or to further enhance it (and check the revision noticed I added to explain the reason for my edit ...). Apart from that: +1 !